# Get current symbolic directory with pathlib

Tags: python-3.x

When executing a Python 3 script in a symbolic directory, I want to get the non-dereferenced path of the current directory. However, the default behavior of `pathlib` returns the derefenced path:

```
 $ mkdir test1
 $ ln -s test1 test2
 $ cd test2
 $ pwd
/home/myuser/test2
$ ipython3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Oct  9 2018, 10:31:47) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from pathlib import Path                                                                                                                  

In [2]: str(Path.cwd())                                                                                                                                
/home/myuser/test1
```

The behavior I want is to get "/home/myuser/test2" as that's where the 'script' (interpreter in this case) was executed from, preferably using `pathlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.getenv('PWD')`:

Directories:

```
$ ls -l
total 1
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cody agroup 0 Dec 11 15:23 dir1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 cody agroup 4 Dec 11 15:23 dir2 -> dir1
```

Result from `dir2`:

```
>>> str(Path.cwd())
'/home/cody/so/dir1'
>>> os.getenv('PWD')
'/home/cody/so/dir2'
```